# Making a module partially imported

Tags: python, import, circular-dependency

I have a package with a couple of modules `config`, and `logging` (amongst others).

The `logging` module provides a method to log to the package's log file (which is defined in the `config` module).

The `config` module contains a bunch of static config values (hardcoded) as well as some dynamic ones loaded from a file.

**`mypackage/logging.py`**

```
import mypackage.config

def log(message):
    log_file = mypackage.config.log_file
    open(log_file, "a").write(message + "\n")
```

**`mypackage/config.py`**

```
import mypackage.logging

log_file = "/var/log/mypackage.log"

try:
    # Load some more config from file.
except Exception as e:
    # That's fine, just log that we couldn't open the file.
    mypackage.logging.log("Couldn't open config file: %s" % str(e))
```

The problem is that the above code suffers from a circular dependency problem, where calling `mypackage.logging.log()` from `mypackage/config.py` before it has finished importing means that the `log_file = mypackage.config.log_file` line in `mypackage/logging.py` will fail.

**Is it possible to import the static portion of `mypackage/config.py` into the module so that is available at `mypackage.config.log_file` when `mypackage.logging.log()` is called?**

Failing that, is there a neater way I can design this without this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your current code work you can import `config.log_file` in `log` function:

```
def log(message):
    from mypackage.config import log_file
    open(log_file, "a").write(message + "\n")
```

Of course, you have a lot of possibilities to redesign the whole system.
For instance, you can put all settings which can produce a circular dependency into their own config file and import it from both `logging.py` and `config.py`.